# selenium xpath to fetch the value of element which has no id associated to it

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selector

I wanted to fetch the value 606 from the following code for selenium

```
<div class="price pad-15 per-person budget-pp marg-left-10 ">
<span>From</span>
<h2 class="size-28 dis-inblock">
<span class="size-22">£</span>
606
</h2>
<span>Per person</span>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me with identifying xpath for the value 606. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide other samples of data set since it will be hard to give you a generic solution (here, I would simplify go for `//div/h2/text()`)

Comment: Hi Xenos, I was able to find by "text() ". Thank You :)

Comment: Ok, so I made an answer out of it so you can accept it.

Comment: Hi Xenos, the element is getting identifies when i check it manually in firebug. But it is not identifying when I run selenium script. Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: Selenium does not accept selecting a non-element node (like `text()`, `comment()` or attributes). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975881/selenium-xpath-to-fetch-the-value-of-element-which-has-no-id-associated-to-it?noredirect=1#comment67235223_39976646 So you will have to select the h2 and extract the text value from it (see other answers)

Answer (score 1):

`XPath` for element that contains `606` is:

```
//h2[span[text()="£"]]
```

You can fetch value with appropriate method in your programming language (like `.get_attribute("text")` or `.text` in `Python`')

Let me know in case of any issues

Answer (score 0):

`//div/h2/text()` here is enough.

`//text()[. = '606']` would be too (but I doubt it's what you require here!)

Comment: FYI `text()` node of the `xpath` does not support to getting text using selenium. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Oh, that's right, I've forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `cssSelector` as well :-

```
div.price.per-person > h2
```

(Assuming you're using Java) Now you can use [`WebElement#getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) to fetching the desired text after locating element using above selector, this would fetch text as `£606`, you can use some programming stuff to omit `£` and get actual value which you want.